# Azure devops artefact retention

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I’ve got a mono repo, which has 10 separate CICD pipelines written in yaml.

I’ve noticed lately that we’ve lost a vast number of runs, and some of them had successful production releases.

Am I right in thinking that the project rententiob settings applies to all pipelines? Rather than individual?

I’ve been reading on the ms website and I think in order to retain them going forward, I have to use the API via a powershell script.

I assume the said script needs to run after a successful deployment to production.

I’m quite surprised that there isn’t a global option to say ‘keep all production releases’

Answer (score 0):

The project Retention policy settings will be applied to all pipeline runs not individual. So you could not use this setting to retention specific successful production releases directly.

To achieve this, you could use the PowerShell script to retention these specific runs with "Condition". Add the PowerShell script as the last task of your deployment to check if this one needs to be retained. Refer to this official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/run-retention?view=azure-devops

Here is an example to retention forever based on condition:

```
- powershell: |
   $contentType = "application/json";
   $headers = @{ Authorization = 'Bearer $(System.AccessToken)' };
   $rawRequest = @{ daysValid = 365000 ; definitionId = $(System.DefinitionId); ownerId = 'User:$(Build.RequestedForId)'; protectPipeline = $false; runId = $(Build.BuildId) };
   $request = ConvertTo-Json @($rawRequest);
   $uri = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/retention/leases?api-version=6.0-preview.1";
   Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType -Body $request;
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
  condition: {Your customize condition}
```